# Open local html file from link in page loaded in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control which I use to display dynamically generated html pages with different info, including html links.  Pages are loaded using webBrowser.DocumentText.

If I include a link to an external webpage, e.g. "https://somesite.com/file.htm" the link works fine, but if I link to a local file, e.g. "file:///c:\temp\file.htm", nothing happens when I click the link.

If I grab the source from the page in the WebBrowser control, save it as an html file and open it in Edge, the link works fine.

I've been browsing through a ton of webpages trying to find a solution but no luck, none of them seem to address this specific problem which I find strange, as it would seem like a common problem.

```
   string htmlCode = "<html><body><a href=\"file:///c:\\temp\\testlink.htm\">link</a></body></html>";
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful if you provided a sample that reproduces the problem you're seeing, but here's one way to do it.

The code below writes two files: `start.html`, which contains a clickable link to the second file, `end.html`, which just contains some text.

Drop a webbrowser control onto the form and run the code. The first page will load with a link you can click, and when you click it, the second page loads.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Modify these with paths on your machine
    var startPage = @"f:\private\temp\start.html";
    var endPage = @"f:\private\temp\end.html";

    // This will write the contents of the files above (so they exist)
    File.WriteAllText(startPage, $"<a href=\"file:///{endPage}\">Click Here</a>");
    File.WriteAllText(endPage, "You did it!!");

    // Navigate to the first file so you can click the link
    webBrowser1.Navigate(startPage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I know you can do that but I was trying to avoid this workaround.  Is there really no way the WebBrowser can open a local file directly?

Comment: What do you mean? The `Navigate` method *is* opening a local file directly.

Comment: It's loading a local file to start, and then again on clicking the link

Comment: Well I have to save the html code containing the link to disk before opening it, instead of loading it from a string using webBrowser.DocumentText.  And the data requires encryption which means encrypting when saving to disk and then decrypting again when reading it.  All in all it decreases performance.

Comment: Besides, WebBrowser.Navigate() can't parse the file on disk as it is encrypted, all it will do is show the encrypted string.  So unless there is a way to encrypt a file that the WebBrowser can decrypt automatically (SSL/TLS?) it won't work.

Comment: You should mention the encryption issue in your question and provide a sample of the codes that's not working.

Comment: Well I didn't expect encryption to be relevant since I expected it was possible to make local links work when using webBrowser.DocumentText (seems really stupid that Microsoft hasn't made this possible).  And I did try to post an html sample but stackoverflow  kept insisting on converting it into plain text so I gave up.  Anyway, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Your question says, *"but if I link to a local file, e.g. "file:///c:\temp\file.htm", nothing happens when I click the link"*. Show the code where you're trying to do this.

Comment: I've added a test sample to my original post.